# Summing Excel Values in rows and columns for conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using Excel, how does one sum the values in all the cells of a group of cells in rows and columns which have values greater then zero (positive)  into a total sum of the positive values, and separately sum the cells in the same group which have values less than zero (negative) into a total of the negative values to obtain separately the resulting positive and negative sums displayed in two separate cells?

Does one write the formula in CountIf or some other formula type?

Comment: If you want sums, use SUMIF.  It will handle a range that is a block of rows and columns.  Use one in one cell for positive values and one in another cell for negative values.  They will be the same formula except one will use `>` and one will use `<`.  Give it a try and if you run into problems, post back with the problem (sample data, your formula, and what result you're getting).

Comment: You need to apply conditional SUM for +ve & -ve numbers,, better [Edit] your post and add some sample data, will help us to suggest the best one to you.

Comment: To add to @fixer1234 his comment, the comparison operator `<` and `>` needs to be wrapped into double quotes. So for example, in range `A1:B5` with both negative and positive values, the `SUMIF` would look like: `=SUMIF(A1:B6,">0")` for positive values, and `=SUMIF(A1:B6,"<0")` for negative.

Comment: @JvdV,, better post all these as an answer instead of comment, help OP and others too ☺

Answer (score 1):

Some mock-up sample data in range `A1:B5`:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUMIF(A1:B6,">0")
```

Formula in `E3`:

```
=SUMIF(A1:B6,"<0")
```

Notice how the comparison operator is wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: Many Thanks and Kindest Regards for your precise answers.